# What is the easiest way to setup my mac to do polymer component development?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Is there a a simple way to setup a development environment to do polymer component development via the [polymer-cli](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 - Install XCode

Step 2 - Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Step 3 - Install bower and node

```
brew install bower
```

Step 4 - Install the [polymer command line](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli)

```
npm install -g polymer-cli
```

Step 5 - Verify the polymer command line is installed

```
polymer help
```

Additional - This allows for homebrew to keep the tools up to date

```
brew update
brew upgrade
npm update -g polymer-cli
```